# Can anyone provide guidance on debugging this minidump from a BSOD?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have a Dell XPS L501X running 64-bit Windows 7. The following [BSOD](http://ge.tt/8c4OOU8?c) has occurred five times in the last three days. Can anyone help me determine how to fix this issue?

Comment: Upload the actual dump file(s) found in Windows\Minidump folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the Debugging Tools from the Windows SDK and load the dump into WinDbg and then run `analyze` (or, for more output, `analyze -v`).

This might tell you what driver is triggering the BSOD, but this cannot always be determined.

This is the same information you get if you allow Windows Error Reporting to upload the dump to Microsoft.

Remember that a BSOD is likely to be either hardware or a driver. If you stick to the MS checked drivers that should reduce the latter leaving hardware. The content of the dump is unlikely to help much with a hardware fault (eg. overheating will not lead to specific data in the dump).

Answer (score 0):

[Bug Check 0xD1: DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560244%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

This is almost always a driver issue, the actual dump file may be able to reveal which driver caused the crash.

C:\Windows\Minidump is the location of the xxxxxx.dmp file. The names are date coded.

Upload it somewhere so one of us can run a crash analysis on it.